# How to recover local backup of S3 that was copied in binaries

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I used the AWS CLI to copy an entire s3 bucket using the command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket C://localfolder --recursive
```

All the files were copied, the names were preserved and the index.html was downloaded correctly. The folder structure was copied correctly. But all the other files (images, js, css and other files) are binaries with the same size and filename.

When copying back to mybucket, the files are not converted back to the original file.

How can I recover all those files that are in binary?

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by *"are binaries with the same size and filename."*  S3 doesn't modify the content.

Comment: Almost all files except for the index.html were downloaded in binary (or encrypted idk) with the same filename and size they had on the bucket. But locally, these are useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make a couple test files in your S3 bucket public and view them in your browser, just to ensure that they are not corrupted in any way. Otherwise, if they're hosed in S3, then there's probably no point in pulling them down. If you make them public, view them, and they're fine, then go ahead and **set them back to private** and then do the next step which is...

...verify the checksum(s) of the file(s) in question:

```
aws s3api head-object --bucket YOUR_BUCKET_NAME --key YOUR_FILE_NAME
```

Check the ETag value against the md5 checksum of the local file. If they match, AND when you made the file public found that it was fine, but they're still borked locally, then it's safe-ish to say it's probably an issue on your local workstation.

As an example of what I mentioned above:

```
M04:Desktop aaron$ md5 cat0.jpg
md5: cat0.jpg: No such file or directory
M04:Desktop aaron$ aws s3api head-object --bucket MY_BUCKET_NAME --key cat0.jpg
{
    "AcceptRanges": "bytes",
    "LastModified": "Sat, 09 Jun 2018 06:53:13 GMT",
    "ContentLength": 286388,
    "ETag": "\"e9b0f5e7647e0bc1ad01745730329d74\"",
    "ContentType": "image/jpeg",
    "Metadata": {}
}
M04:Desktop aaron$ aws s3 cp s3://MY_BUCKET_NAME/cat0.jpg .
download: s3://MY_BUCKET_NAME/cat0.jpg to ./cat0.jpg       
M04:Desktop aaron$ md5 cat0.jpg
MD5 (cat0.jpg) = e9b0f5e7647e0bc1ad01745730329d74
M04:Desktop aaron$
```

Note that my cat picture's checksum in both locations (in S3 BEFORE I downloaded it, then on my local workstation AFTER I downloaded it) match. I also confirmed that I can open this picture locally and see a grumpy looking cat, so all's good.

Comment: Thank you, I lost all the original files because I copied back the localfolder to mybucket and the bucket was in deed hosting a website. I can't open any of the files in my local directory and when copied back to the bucket, these are useless.

Comment: I swear I've typed this response three times now. Anyways, as I understand it, you originally had working files on your local workstation that you uploaded to S3. Then you downloaded them all back to your local workstation, but found them to be corrupted? After that, did you then re-upload them back to the same S3 bucket? If so, then yeah, that will have overwritten the existing files, UNLESS you had Versioning enabled. If you do, then you can try to revert a few files and confirm they're no longer corrupt, and/or verify the checksums.

Comment: The files don't seem to be corrupted, just encoded. I was looking for a way to revert that encoding/encryption